# What happens when an object doesn't absorb all the heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature

Well, we give the same quantity of heat to two objects. If these ones are different, they have different temperature. So the objects absorb different quantity of heat and they release a different quantity. But why this? I know that some are conductors and some not, but why this? What happens in the microscopic world? For example, consider gold and wood. If the temperature increases, the kinetic energy of the particles increases. So what's the difference with the wood? The particles aren't heavier. So does wood release more heat? And why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No they absorb the same quantity of heat but reach different temperatures - depending on their [specific heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_heat_capacity).

Think of it as some springs being stronger than others. If you put the same force on a big spring as a small spring it compresses less. If you put the same amount of heat energy into water (high specific heat capacity) as air (low heat capacity) - the water will reach a much lower temperature.

Comment: Yes, but why? I mean, they have specific heat capacity because they are different substances. But why? What do the particles do?

Comment: A combination of the masses of the atoms and the strength of the bonds. It takes more heat to make heavy molecules with strong bonds move. The amount of movement is the temperature.

Comment: But for example the gold is quite heavy but it has a low specific heat capacity

Comment: Metals tend to have low specific heat capacity because the bonds are very elastic. Energy put in immediately makes all the atoms vibrate (=higher temperature) molecules like water with complex / strong bonds absorb the energy you put in without the molecules moving much. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dulong%E2%80%93Petit_law